# Touchableopacity onPress is not working with react navigation

Tags: react-native

how do I use touchable opacity in my code if my next screen is SplashScreen2

```html
<TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.buttonText]}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigateToScreen("SplashScreen2")}
              >
                <Text style={[styles.buttonContent, { color: "white" }]}>
                  Next
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

Change to ->

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SplashScreen2')}
```

Comment: navigateToScreen -> navigate

Comment: Actually that is not working I tried that

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
    <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.buttonText]}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SplashScreen2")} // change navigateToScreen to navigate
    >
          <Text style={[styles.buttonContent, { color: "white" }]}>
            Next
          </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: This didnt even work

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I had some issues with my styling part it was problem with my expo-app anyways thanks for the clarification